# How to set rgl label colors

Tags: r, rgl

I am trying to set label colours to `"black"`. However, when using `rgl.triangles()` with `col="lightgray"`, the label text is also set to `"lightgray"` which is too light for the printed image. Is it possible to set the label text colour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in calling `rgl.triangles()`.  If you call `triangles3d()` instead, it won't have the side effect of changing the default colour.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer from a search on the Internet. Apparently, one needs to include

```
rgl.material(color="#000000")
```

before using `decorate3d()` even though this call has an option to set colour, which does not appear to do the job.